# Time out error in Lambda on ws connection to websocket server hosted on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, websocket, aws-lambda

Getting error on execution of Lambda, In Lambda(Client WS), trying to establish connection and send messages on Websocket server hosted on EC2.

If i reboot EC2 then, only first time Lambda runs successfully and server receives message but subsequent Lambda calls fails with error "Time out in 3 sec"

```
// Node JS --- Hosted on EC2
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8085 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
    });
  });

  ws.send(JSON.stringify({status:'Connected'}));

// Lambda
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://ec2-public-ip.com:8085');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Getting Error : Time out in 3.xx sec

Thank You!